# Why is the Google Sign-In not working in angular web app in Angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, google-api, google-signin

I am trying to get google sign in my web app. I tried to follow this tutorial[Google sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) But even the google sign-in button is not showing.
I want to have my authentication at http://localhost:4200/home, not at http://localhost:4200

Here is what my home HTML looks like

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="998210766859-ag7cijtb0md9cj6oj9nvqis5kk8g7929.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>


<br>
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Here is corresponding component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BlogService } from '../blog.service';
import { Blogpost } from '../blogpost';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-frontpage',
  templateUrl: './frontpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./frontpage.component.css']
})

export class FrontpageComponent implements OnInit {
  public lis = [];
  public l1 ="siba";
  constructor(private servo:BlogService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.servo.getblogs()
    .subscribe(data => this.lis = data);
  }

  onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
  }

}
```

The last part is the onSignIn function.

But when I run the app the sign-in button is not showing up, just sign out anchor tag is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package angularx-social-login [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login),It is easy to implement.